# e-commerce store using drupal

Tags: drupal

What is the difference between ubercart module and commerce module in drupal?

Which is better for building a "groupon like" site?

Answer (score 3):

[Ubercart](http://ubercart.org) is your best choice at the moment. If you are talking about Drupal 7, in a little while [Drupal Commerce](http://drupalcommerce.org) will become the best choice but it is still somewhat a moving target. Once it matures a little the power that using Entities/Fields with Rules brings to it is enormous and if you needed to develop Groupon functionality from scratch I think it would be quicker out the gate and more extensible/flexible down the road.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your situation, but if you’re goal is to simply and easily recreate a Groupon site, you can get 90% of the way there by installing the Open Deals Distribution profile:

http://drupal.org/project/opendeals

This is a Commerce install profile (distribution) and it seems to fit your use case quite well.

You’d then use the Mailhandler suite of modules and once you get to scale you could use an external email service provider like MailChimp or CheetahMail.

The Commerce platform is highly extensible, as is Ubercart, but since it uses the Entity paradigm you have more control over how to display your content with Views/ Panels.  Check here for a list of the current contrib modules: http://www.drupalcommerce.org/contrib/all

Answer (score 0):

Drupal Commerce will become the future Ubercart, I believe. It is still in alpha development though and on the project page it says there are no upgrade paths supporting version to version- your best bet is still Ubercart.

Answer (score 0):

There's a healthy and helpful discussion on the drupal.stackexchange.com forum about ubercart/drupal commerce:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5/which-e-commerce-module-for-drupal-7